# primer3 web error , Unrecognized tag, primer3_core Unrecognized tag

Tags: apache, cgi, bioinformatics, primer3

I tried to run a primer3 web on localhost , but there was an error on the output when the pick primer.

Primer3 Output:

> Unrecognized tag: PRIMER_THERMODYNAMIC_ALIGNMENT=1 ./primer3_core:
>   Unrecognized tag: PRIMER_THERMODYNAMIC_ALIGNMENT=1
>
> INPUT PROBLEM: Unrecognized tag: PRIMER_THERMODYNAMIC_ALIGNMENT=1
>
> (primer3_results.cgi release 3.0.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that they eliminated the param **PRIMER_THERMODYNAMIC_ALIGNMENT**. Now you should use either **PRIMER_THERMODYNAMIC_OLIGO_ALIGNMENT** or **PRIMER_THERMODYNAMIC_TEMPLATE_ALIGNMENT**. Take a look at the following link:

http://primer3.sourceforge.net/primer3_manual.htm

Section "5. CHANGES FROM VERSION 2.2.3". I suppose you use a new version greater than 2.2.3 which has the new arguments.

Comment: yes I am using the latest version 2.3.6 and I use the web primer3 v.3.0.0 . how to fix

Comment: @irwanDwiyanto It's a bug in the system, ask the devs to fix it or use version 4.0.0 (which seems to work [http://bioinfo.ut.ee/primer3/](http://bioinfo.ut.ee/primer3/) )

Comment: nice good i using primer3 web version 4.0.0 running with localhost, thanks